# Display dynamic Navigation menu in asp.net core mvc layout page

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to display dynamic menu in asp.net core mvc layout page. in my database table has menuid and parentid from that i want to display nested menus. if anyone have solution please help me and if any other method for this give an example.
Model is given below:

```
  public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MenuText { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public List<Menu> List { get; set; }

}
```

I want to use this in my layout class .How can i use this?

```
db_class Connstring = new db_class();
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var user_id = Convert.ToString(context.Request["Id"]); 
        var str_company = Convert.ToString(context.Request["str_company"]);

        List<Menu> listMenu = new List<Menu>();

        string query = @"SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Privilege.Name AS MenuText, dbo.[Right].[Add], dbo.[Right].Edit, dbo.[Right].[Delete], dbo.[Right].[view], dbo.[Right].Status AS Active, dbo.Privilege.URL AS url, 
        dbo.Privilege.ParentID AS ParentId, dbo.[Right].PrivilegeID AS menu_id, dbo.[Right].UserID, dbo.Company.Code, dbo.Company.Name, dbo.Privilege.ID
        FROM            dbo.Privilege INNER JOIN
        dbo.[Right] ON dbo.Privilege.ID = dbo.[Right].PrivilegeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.Module ON dbo.Privilege.ModuleID = dbo.Module.ID INNER JOIN
        dbo.Department ON dbo.Module.DepartmentID = dbo.Department.ID INNER JOIN
        dbo.Company ON dbo.Department.CompanyID = dbo.Company.ID
        WHERE        (dbo.[Right].Status = 1) AND (dbo.[Right].UserID = '" + user_id.Trim() + "') AND (dbo.Company.Code = '" + str_company.Trim() + "') AND (dbo.Privilege.Platform = 'Web') AND (dbo.Module.Platform = 'Web') OR (dbo.[Right].Status = 1) AND(dbo.[Right].UserID = '" + user_id.Trim() + "') AND(dbo.Privilege.ParentID IS NULL) ORDER BY dbo.Privilege.Priority, dbo.Privilege.ID";

        using (SqlConnection con = Connstring.getcon)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                menu.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["menu_id"]);
                menu.MenuText = rdr["MenuText"].ToString();
                menu.ParentId = rdr["ParentId"] != DBNull.Value
                    ? Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ParentId"]) : (int?)null;
                menu.Url = rdr["url"].ToString();
                menu.Active = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Active"]);
                listMenu.Add(menu);
            }
        }
        List<Menu> menuTree = GetMenuTree(listMenu, null);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(menuTree));
    }
    public List<Menu> GetMenuTree(List<Menu> list, int? parent)
    {
        return list.Where(x => x.ParentId == parent).Select(x => new Menu
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            MenuText = x.MenuText,
            ParentId = x.ParentId,
            Url = x.Url,
            Active = x.Active,
            List = GetMenuTree(list, x.Id)
        }).ToList();
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the javascript code :

```
var sl = 0;
        function buildMenu(parent, items) {
            $.each(items, function () {
                //alert(this.MenuText);
                //var icon = this.icon;
                //if (icon == "") {
                var icon = 'fa fa-circle-o';
                //}
                //------------------------------------//
                if (this.List && this.List.length > 0) {
                    var pull_right = '</span><span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>';
                    icon = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign";
                }
                else
                    pull_right = '';
                //------------------------------------//
                sl = sl + 1;
                span_id = '';
                if (this.Url != "") {
                    span_id = 'id="active_span_m' + sl + '"';
                }
                else {
                    span_id = '';
                }
                //-----------------------------------//
                var li = $('<li id="m' + sl + '" onclick="set_menu_active(\'m' + sl + '\')" alt="' + this.Id + '" class="treeview"><a href="' + this.Url + '"><i class="' + icon + '"></i><span ' + span_id + '>' + this.MenuText + pull_right + '</a></li>');
                li.appendTo(parent);

                if (this.List && this.List.length > 0) {
                    var ul = $('<ul class="treeview-menu menu-open"></ul>');
                    ul.appendTo(li);
                    buildMenu(ul, this.List);
                }
            });
            //---------------Set Session---------------//
            var str = $("<div />").append($("#menu").clone()).html();
            sessionStorage.setItem("str_menu", str);
        }
```

And Ajax:

$.ajax({
                                    url: '../../../../../CDB/System/Common/Layout/Master/Permission.ashx',
                                    method: 'get',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    data: { 'Id': u_s_id, 'str_company': str_company },
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        //alert(data);
                                        buildMenu($('#menu'), data);
                                        $('#menu').menu();
                                    },
                                    error: function (err) {
                                    }
                                });
            Output Image like as 
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWBpf.png)

Now i want to know process of  use of this code in asp.net core mvc layout to get dynamic navigation menu

Comment: You could try [View Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and refer to [Dynamic Navigation Menu from Database](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5163177/MVC-6-Dynamic-Navigation-Menu-from-Database)